# "big-oh" of a block statement

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Can anyone tell me the "big-oh" of this block code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)

   statements1.....
     for(int k = 0; k< 60; k++)
        for(int l = 0; l < 10; i++)
           statements2....
          end l;
      end k;
    for(int g = 1; g < n; g *= 10) 
      for(int h = 1; h < n; h *= 10) 
             statements 3..........
        end h;
     end g;

end j;
end i;
```

I am studying algorithms and I came across this, and because of these many loops I do not understand how to solve.

Comment: never read of it like you spelled on the title, always big-O . Also probably you should correct your code.

Comment: The k and l loops are fixed size so can be ignored. Then you just have four nested loops which I would hope your studies have taught you how to deal with...

Comment: It never finishes execution if n > 0. Look at your code carefully.

Comment: please modify your question, there are lots of things wrong with it.

Comment: `for(int l = 0; l < 10; i++)` You sure about that?

Comment: @interjay yes. thats a type error, actually there are lots of error in this code, i know. but I found it like this only. It got me really confused.

Comment: All these errors make the question rather meaningless. How are we supposed to know what value `g` is supposed to go to, for example? The question as posted can't be answered without making a lot of guesses.

Comment: @interjay you are right, I corrected it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `statements1`, `statements2` and `statements3` should be considered constant time operations.

Now you have the following structure

```
for [0...n]
    for [0...n]
        for [0...60]
            for [0...10]
        for [0...n in exponential steps]
            for [0...n in exponential steps]
```

The `[0...60]` and `[0...10]` parts are `O(1)` since `60` and `10` are constant. The loops with exponential steps can be simplified as follows:

```
for [0...n]
    for [0...n]
        for [0...log n]
            for [0...log n]
```

so you end up with `O(n² * (log n)²)`

Comment: O(n^2 * (log n)^2) = O(n^3)? are you serious?

Comment: yeah I see but it is still wrong, O(n² * (log n)²) = O(n² * log n) is wrong too. O(n² * (log n)²) = O(n² * (log n)²) is correct ;)

Comment: O(n² * (log n)²) cant be any more simpler that is the answer just O(n² * (log n)²)!

Comment: Oh gosh. Mixed up (log n)² with (log n²) fixed now. Thanks Ali, I appreciate the patience :)

Comment: Ok. I understand it now.@aioobe Thanks! and sorry for so many type errors in the code. I found it like this only.

Answer (score 0):

First, `statements1` and everything below is executed $n^2$ times. 
But what about the other loops?

For each time `statements1` is executed, `statments2` is executed 600 times, which can be neglected in big-O notation.

What about `statements3`? Well here strange things happen, because this only finishes if `i` is modified somewhere inside of `statements3`. If that however happens, the rest of this analysis is wrong, as `statements1` whill not be executed as often as I thought in the beginning.

If however you meant to write the following:

```
for(int g = 1; g < n; g *= 10) 
  for(int h = 1; h < n; h *= 10)
```

then each of these loops adds a `log(n)` factor, resulting in a total O(n^2 * log^2(n))

All in all: with only this code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Actually not, because l always stays zero.

Comment: @gnasher729, I bet that's a typo.

Comment: Those fixed loops are still infinite because `g` and `h` will always be 0.